# how to use more than one query at php file

Tags: php

I built an html page with some options to insert details for a friends club.
I used an INSERT query and it worked. I want to add other queries like an UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT etc.

this is the php file:

```
<?php
//Input posted data.
$Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
$Lname = $_POST["Lname"];
$Date = $_POST["Date"];
$Mail = $_POST["Mail"];
$Pass = $_POST["Pass"];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',"");

//Check if the connection was opened, if not prompt the error to the page.
if (!$conn)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

//Select the data base.
mysqli_select_db($conn, "club");

//Set the character set to utf-8 to allow hebrew.
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");    

//SQL query - user Details 
$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (Fname, Lname, Mail, Date, Pass) 
          VALUES('$Fname','$Lname','$Mail','$Date','$Pass')";

//Run SQL query
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_connect_errno());


//Close the SQL connection.
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

I want to use those queries in the same file.

how can I do that?

Should I add a new form on the same page?

For example `<form name="input" action="Update.php" method="POST">` to direct it to the `Update.php` file?

can I use more than one form at the same html file?

I've created this form for the Update button on the page to `Update.php` file but it doesn't work. It just adds the details and does not update them, although I used the UPDATE query.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[you are at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even **[escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)** is not safe! I recommend `PDO`, which I [wrote a function for](http://paragoncds.com/grumpy/pdoquery/#function) to make it extremely **easy**, very **clean**, and way more **secure** than using non-parameterized queries.

Comment: Also having a look at this woulde be helpful http://www.codingcage.com/2015/06/multiple-insert-update-delete-crud.html

Answer (score 1):

You take all your PHP code and put it in the head of the form's page, then wrap it all inside

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-button-name'])){
    //YOUR PHP CODE
}
```

Now you for each `submit-button-name` you make an if statement with it, for example

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
  //YOUR INSERT QUERY
}

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
  //YOUR UPDATE QUERY
}

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
  //YOUR DELETE QUERY
}
```

That if you for example have 3 buttons like the following

```
<button type='submit' name='insert'>INSERT</button>
<button type='submit' name='update'>UPDATE</button>
<button type='submit' name='delete'>DELETE</button>
```

Inside the form, of course the `UPDATE & DELETE` queries require an identifier to find the row

```
WHERE id = $id
```

So it depends how you will implement the buttons in one form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !